# optimal view including last value

Tags: sql, view

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ConnectionId INT - primary key, identity,
ServerId INT, 
ClientId INT, 
Time DATETIME, 
ConnectionType INT
```

How do I define an optimal view which returns all combinations of `ServerId` and `ClientId` and time and type of LAST connection for each combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a database that supports ranking functions (such as SQL Server 2005+, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, Teradata . . .), you can do this as follows:

```
create view as
    select ServerId, ClientId, time, type
    from (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by ServerId, ClientId order by time desc) as seqnum
          from t
         ) t
    where seqnum = 1
```

I don't know what you mean by "optimal view".  If you want this to work better, create a three-part index on ServerId, ClientId, and time.

Comment: Brilliant, excellent :) I have never used the ranking function. I going to learn how to use them. I always solved the problem using subqueries and it was not optimal at all. Thanks a lot!